# no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

Im trying to sort a dataset by the number of explicit songs per album and used the following code in R Studio

```
DF <- read.csv("spotify.csv")
df_explicit <- filter(DF,explicit == "True")

df_explicit %/%
  group_by(album_name) %/%
  summarise(count=n())
```

and it returns the following error

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Could someone explain what im doing wrong or how to do this
The dataset in question:https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/maharshipandya/-spotify-tracks-dataset?resource=download

Answer (score 0):

Your pipe operator doesn't look right – try `%>%` or `|>` instead of `%/%`.

Also, `explicit` seems to be a logical value in the original dataset so comparing it to a character string with `explicit == "True"` won't work if you parsed it as such.

This should work:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("spotify.csv")

df |> 
  filter(explicit) |> 
  count(album_name)
```